# Sonar eclipse plugin how to use JDK 7

Tags: eclipse, sonarqube

Hi I am trying to run sonar analysis in eclipse via eclipse plugin, but it got error which suggests it tries to run analyze with JDK 6 when some sonar plugin in server requires jdk 7, but I have configured the default JRE in eclipse as JDK 7 , so why Sonar eclipse still tries to use jdk 7?

my eclipse version: indigo, sonar plugin version: latest.

Answer (score 1):

SQ Eclipse will use by default the same JVM used to start Eclipse. You can override this by passing `-Djava.home=<path to your JVM>` in "JVM arguments for preview analysis" field in Eclipse settings.

Comment: It seems "JVM arguments for preview analysis" can't be used to change JVM , just like you can't run ../jdk6/bin/java -DJAVA_HOME=../jdk7

Comment: It works because execution of SQ is forked (a new VM is started).